# Free apps to bundle two executables together

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I created an MSI application using WIX installer which need .NEt runtime to work. So I bundled both using wix installer and final output was in EXE. Its not showing my MSI installation window but showing default bundle installation window.

Is there a way to install prerequisite in background by showing my MSI window and the final bundle format in MSI.

IF its not possible using wix, IS there any third-party free tool to bundle multiple EXE or MSI together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I found to do it is create your custom bootstrapper. [Here's link with step-by-step guide](https://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/).

Here you have two options:

- Create your own .net installer with UI as described in article;
- Do as described in article but remove showing of custom UI step;

Second one is little bit tricky and I'll recommend you to create your own UI using WPF. It will give you a lot of benefits.